# WinPatrol startup change alert - False alarm?

Tags: windows-7, security, 64-bit

I'm using the Aurora browser which may contain security regression bugs, and this morning i found WinPatrol notifying me about explorer.exe not autostarting anymore, which seemed worrying. However, while the current user registry doesn't appear to contain any autostart entries (Is that normal? WinPatrol later warned me about all other autostarts being removed, presumably from there.), the local machine registry still contains all my autostart entries, which i verified using msconfig and WinPatrol itself:

[image: Original alert plus WinPatrol's HTML report with autostart entries]

The free version of HitmanPro hasn't found anything bad (except possibly PunkBuster and two Softonic registry entries), so should i be worried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Malwarebytes and its anti-rootkit didn't find anything suspicious after a reboot, so i guess it was a false alarm.